# Show/hide fields depending on select value parent/sub

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I want to show some PvP/PK content based on server. I do not need help with the script - I have it. What I need help with is how to properly show the fields. If Custom is selected, it automatically shows the Custom - PvP field content, but you have the option to select the PK field content. When No Custom is selected, it automatically shows No Custom - PvP field content, but you have the option ot select the PK field content. I have a simple show/hide fields content that I found (on here, I think, when I was searching), but I don't know how to add parent/sub (what I need).

Example of what I want:

[image: Example of what I want]

Current script: https://jsfiddle.net/Aiphira/f9q0qjdr/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.viewMap = {
    'view1' : $('#view1'),
    'view2' : $('#view2')
  };

  $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
    // hide all
    $.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
    // show current
    $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="viewSelector">  
   <option value="view1">No Custom</option>
   <option value="view2">Custom</option>
</select>

<div id="view1">
asd
</div>
<div id="view2">
qwe
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the problem description doesn't seem clear enough. Can you be more descriptive using low level terms? Are you trying to hide certain options in the child select element when a specific value is selected in the parent select element?

Comment: @BluePill I want to make the selection like in the photo, but I don't know how. There should be, like, in the first selection, for example, "Mid x75 LIVE" and "PvP x5k LIVE" and in the second "PvP" and "PK". Don't know how to properly explain it ..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f9q0qjdr/1/ Do u mean something like this?

Comment: @user3732702 Yeah, except that it would show automatically when loaded. And you would be able to change the content via the HTML code, not within the javascript (since there will be a lot of php going on there).

Comment: @Aiphira Then u can use jquery $().map function and build tree of elements. Then u can easily operate with it or just use ajax.

Comment: @user3732702 That's the thing - I don't know that much about jquery/javascript to add these things. A little help, pretty please? :)

Comment: @Aiphira https://jsfiddle.net/f9q0qjdr/3/ thats it

Comment: @user3732702 Umm, not working properly. Check it (between Something1 and Something2, when I choose Something2 it still shows Something1). And how to create normal divs for PVE (there are for PVP but not for PVE) ?

Comment: @Aiphira https://jsfiddle.net/f9q0qjdr/4/ fixed, what do u mean when saying "normal"? I created both pve and pvp server types